# CSS table layout has big space between cells

Tags: html, css

I am writing a website at the moment that has a header containing a logo and a tagline. The image is fixed width, and I want the tagline to take up all the space next to the image and to be vertically aligned with the image, so I'm using the following code:

```
<div id="header">
    <img id="logo" src="images/logo.png"/>
    <div id="tagline">
        <p>Tagline text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the css I am using `display: table` for the header and `display: table-cell` for the image and the tagline div. This almost achieves what I want, except that there's a big gap between the image and the tagline. I have tried setting the following properties on the header, but can't get rid of the gap. The gap gets smaller and disappears as the browser width decreases, so I guess it's some kind of cell spacing. How do I get the tagline to fill the space?

```
#header {   
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

For a more complete example, see http://jsfiddle.net/5LJNw/3/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

CSS

```
#tagline {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width:100%;   // set width to 100%
    background-color: #CFE0D6;

}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5LJNw/10/)

Comment: That did the trick, thank you! I don't know why I didn't think of that, seems obvious!